# Django ManyToManyField in admin value list

Tags: django

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    landing = models.ManyToManyField(Place, related_name="landing_schedule", null=False)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s | %s' % (self.departure, self.landing)
```

How can i display the values inside admin for the ManyToManyField ?

Comment: Do you have a preference for how they appear? Have you registered an admin class for this model? If so, they should appear by default on the detail page.

Comment: I have registered with: `class ScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [search_flights]` but I getting only: Rio | flyerapp.Place.None:

Comment: Oh, are you only talking about the string that gets returned? Or are you also not able to set the M2M relationships inside the admin?

Comment: Only the result string of M2M. There is a way to get the related Place results?

Comment: I added an answer that returns a string formatted like: `Departure | Landing1, Landing2, Landing3`. I tested it on Py3.4.2/Django1.7.8, so let me know if it isn't backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Place` has a `name` field, the following should do what you want.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s | %s' % (self.departure, ", ".join(l.name for l in self.landing.all()))
```

Depending on how many records you have and how many relationships, it might cause a performance hit, so be careful.

Comment: Yes, it is compatible. I'm thinking why didn't tryed before. I will put a limit to prevent performance issues. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Good idea on the limit; however, if you start seeing problems it could be all of the `self.landing.all()` calls. If the Departure-Landing relationship if only edited in Schedule, you could make a 'joined landing string' field that gets updated whenever Schedule is saved and then use that in your return string.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method as below and make it display in admin list display
model.py

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    landing =models.ManyToManyField(Place,related_name="landing_schedule", null=False)
    #
    # 
    def list_of_landing(self):
        return ",".join([x.something for x in self.place.all()])
```

admin.py

```
class ScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('list_of_landing')
```